# Every point of an open ball is a centre for the open ball.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ is  a nonempty set and $d$ is an ultrametric on $X$ i.e.,$$d(x,y)\le\max\{d(x,z),d(z,y)\}$$ for all $x,y \in X$. Suppose B is an open ball of $(X,d)$. Show that every point of B is a centre for B.

I can't understand the statement I have to prove as how can an open ball have more than one centre . Please Help!!

I found the problem from Searcoid's Book on Metric Space!

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose $B$ has radius $r$ and center $p$. Take $q \in B$. You must prove that $$\{x \in X \mid d(x,p) < r \} = \{x \in X \mid d(x,q)<r \}.$$

Comment: please can you give an example??

Comment: ok i have understood!!